# Do I need to modify this mod-rewrite code if I add an SSL certificate to my server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

*This is a follow-up to a question I asked last year about setting up mod-rewrites: http://bit.ly/h8PVd9*

I have the following mod-rewrite on my server which forces all traffic to use the full URL (*for the sake of this question, I'll use www.mysite.com*). It's working fine and there are no issues:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So that's all well and good, however I need to add an SSL to the server, covering the domain *www.mysite.com*. What (if any) modification/exception do I need to add to my pre-existing rewrite code to ensure any calls to ***https***://www.mysite.com won't be redirected to *http://www.mysite.com*? Do I need to revise anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing and consulting with my webhost, the answer to this question is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first rule addresses all https requests to the server and allows them through without getting redirected by my original rules. The second is a re-write of my original rules, and addresses the forced use of www.mysite.com regardless of what the user types in.

@Paul - you were pretty close on this one, but with my existing re-writes this solution solves both issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a rewrite expert, but I think below will work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect anyone anywhere, in fact the opposite! Sorry if that wasn't clear. I want to make sure secure calls to https pages aren't redirected to insecure http pages given the syntax of the rewrite above.

Comment: Alright, I removed my second example. So the one shown will only redirect if it is http. If it is https, then it does not make it through the conditions.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond